# How to use an input language different from the keyboard layout country and from the system language?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

- My system language is set to `English` and I want it to stay that way
- My keyboard layout is set to `USA intl` and I want it to stay that way
- I can't write `ç`, by pressing <kbd>´</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. When I try to do so it outputs `ć`
- In Windows the keyboard layout country can be different from both system and input languages, which in their turn can be different from each other.
- I want to achieve the same with Ubuntu

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5095/typing-using-key-combinations

Comment: @kounryusui the answers may be similar, but the question is totally different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keyboard layouts are not dependent to countries (some countries don't have a keyboard layout, some have multiple, some keyboard-layouts are used in several countries, some keyboard layouts have no relation to any country, etc.).

So just change the keyboard layout to something else (I would suggest "US International with AltGr dead keys", or maybe to something else that you are used to).

---

**Edit:** it seems like by default US international behaves differently on Windows than in X; in Windows `'` followed by `c` gives `ç`, while in X it gives `ć`.

---

**Edit 2:** okay, so I found a solution, but it doesn't work in Gtk/GNOME applications because of a stupid bug...

Create a file `~/.XCompose` and put the following lines in it:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
<dead_acute> <C>        : "Ç" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_acute> <c>        : "ç" ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

---

**Edit 3:** Actually it does work in Gtk too when you select XIM as the import method for Gtk, and make sure it's selected in the Language Support dialog.

Comment: I'm telling you. I am used to "US intl" set to Portuguese language. Your answer is not helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "input language"?  I have never seen an option to set that in any Windows version, and I have used most of them since 2.01 ?

Comment: Are you sure what you need is not one of the Portuguese or Brazilian layouts?

Comment: All Windows versions since 95 at least have this option. Look at [this image](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_e1IlgcNcTSg/R6PqJrtppKI/AAAAAAAAB6s/PoBiZZ9KNO4/japanese_keyboard.jpg?imgmax=400) for instance. First you have to choose the input language, and then you will choose the keyboard layout.

Comment: @JanC I don't like Portuguese or Brazilian layouts.

Comment: That's just a way to choose the language to use for spell checking etc., and doesn't change anything about the keyboard layout?

Comment: I think the problem is that US international is different between linux/X & Windows...

Comment: @JanC it's not about spell checking only, in Windows it really changes the behavior of some keys, like the combination of diacritics and letters

Comment: @JanC It may be different, but I haven't detected any difference in the layout per se, just in the behavior

Comment: @Jader: I tested US intl with English, Portuguese & Dutch in Windows, and it didn't change anything (`'`+`c`=`ç`), and I've never seen it change anything, but maybe it's true with other combinations...

Comment: `ć` is a Polish letter. but with Polish as input language in Windows 7 it still outputs `ç`. this strengthens your argument and weakens mine.

Answer (score 3):

> My keyboard layout is set to USA intl and I want it to stay that way

So, in particular, <kbd>'</kbd> is a dead key, right? (I can't be sure because there are several keyboard layouts that you might have abbreviated “USA intl”. To avoid ambiguities, use the exact full name in your question.)

> I can't write ç, by pressing '+c. When I try to do so it outputs ć

That's normal. Acute accent + lowercase C = lowercase C with acute. You picked a “USA intl” keyboard variant, it has no reason to favor the characters used in Portuguese over the characters used in Polish.

<sub>(Windows's “USA International” does give you `ç` for `'`+`C`, but that's because their idea of “international” is “some Western European languages, with only [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_8859-1) characters”. Since `ć` is not in the latin1 character set, the combination `'`+'C' is mapped in a counter-intuitive way to a different character that does exist and is not otherwise accessible.)</sub>

If <kbd>'</kbd> is indeed a dead key, you can change the characters it generates to specialize to your favorite language. There's no GUI for that, you have to write a configuration file. Copy `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` to `.XCompose` in your home directory. In `.XCompose`, look for lines that read

```
<dead_acute> <C> : "Ć"   U0106 # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
<dead_acute> <c> : "ć"   U0107 # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH ACUTE
```

and replace them by

```
<dead_acute> <C> : "Ç"   Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_acute> <c> : "ç"   ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **add** another keyboard layout, there will appear a new indicator icon that let's you chose which one you want to be active. 
[image]

You can have as many as you want and change them on the fly. If you found one that works properly (which "US Alternate International" should do), you can remove all others and the indicator will disappear.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help me

Comment: If you do what I described, you should be able to enter ç by pressing the `right Alt` key and `<`. Could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I want to be able to enter `ç` exactly as I do on Windows, and not by an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

Goto System-->Preferences-->IBus Preferences it will show you a window click yes
[image]

After clicking Yes.Another window will be shown like the one you see below
[image]

You can change the input method to any language according to your wish and click add.New language will be added now.Now you can type in the selected languages,just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle between the languages..For example if you choose Hindi, pressing **Ctrl+Space** will allow you to type in **Hindi** if you press **Ctrl+Space** again you can type in **English**.

**Note:**

If you are using ubuntu 10.10 you should install the following

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib ibus-gtk
```

To type this `ç` character.Goto System-->Keyboard-->Layouts and click **Options**
[image]

Check **Right Alt** and then click close.
[image]

Now Hold <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> and then press <kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>  it will give you **ç**

Comment: I haven't found IBus Preferences under System => Preferences in Ubuntu Desktop 10.10 amd64

Comment: You should install ibus in ubuntu 10.10.I have updated my post see above.

Comment: Installed, how do I start it with the link still missing?

Comment: It will be under System-->Preferences-->IBus if it's not there type  **ibus-setup** in terminal.

Comment: I had to go with the second option. It has only options for languages which use a character set very different from english.

Comment: See this post http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2007/06/05/how_to_get_special_characters_easily_in_ubuntu.html

Comment: Do you want to type this character ç ??

Comment: yes. ç is the char