# Same keyboard layout, different outputs for different languages

Tags: 13.04, keyboard-layout

- I have a UK keyboard, so UK-English layout
- Need to type Portuguese and German characters (e.g. á, ã, ä...)
- Don't want to buy a new keyboard
- Don't want to change keyboard layout (standard Ubuntu functionality)
- Why not? Because I don't want to constantly "try to remember" where each key is; I most definitely don't want to print a layout map either!
- I want to press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and get `'a` when language is English or German and `á` when Portuguese; currently, to get `á` in Portuguese I need to press <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- This is possible/standard in Windows since 98 (to my knowledge)
- I'm aware of the following question, but it didn't help me: [How to use an input language different from the keyboard layout country and from the system language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14202/how-to-use-an-input-language-different-from-the-keyboard-layout-country-and-from)
- Why not? Because it suggests to change the keyboard layout, which is what I strictly want to avoid

> > So is it possible to achieve different outputs while maintaining the underlying keyboard layout (to match its physical layout)?

Comment: So you want to be able to use the same input but with different outputs during different settings, isn't that the same as different layouts? Just mod a layout in the way you want it..

Comment: @Alvar Sounds like a good idea; so how do you 'mod a layout' in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: @Alvar: What I need/want is not the same as changing layouts. If I change the keyboard layout (straightforward change in Ubuntu 13.04), outputs do not correspond to the physical keys I press on the keyboard. Do you understand the point?

Comment: What about this http://www.dotkam.com/2007/06/25/custom-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu-or-just-linux-2/ ?

Comment: @0R10N: Thanks fro the help, but that sounds like a lot of manual work to get around this problem; I'm still looking for a simple solution...

Comment: What you want is a normal us keyboard but one with a different mod for the a key to output another character. I would have 3 layouts, us-with-Portuguese-A normal US,  and us-with-German characters added. so you have 3 basic us layouts, but change the characters you want for each language.

Comment: Then simple add like a shortcut command to toggle the next layout, like F3.

Comment: @Alvar: Excellent idea! It's what I've had in mind the whole time though... what you're suggesting is what one would normally do in Windows (see [this](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_e1IlgcNcTSg/R6PqJrtppKI/AAAAAAAAB6s/PoBiZZ9KNO4/japanese_keyboard.jpg?imgmax=400) pic in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14202/how-to-use-an-input-language-different-from-the-keyboard-layout-country-and-from) question). Great! Now how do you do this in Linux?

Comment: well tell you when I get home to my Ubuntu computer, can't remember right now...

Comment: @Alvar: Aham... Alvar, have you been home yet? :) Sorry, this forum is not a place for jokes... but I'm desperate to find a solution to this, since I'm writing both a code and a paper with English, French, Portuguese and German words :o

Comment: Solved! In the end both Alvar and the above mentioned question pointed at the right direction. The solution is really meant to be "layout changing" in Ubuntu... even though I still strongly disagree with such a label: the change is in behaviour of certain key combinations (input) to achieve desired characters (output), not in layout (physical arrangement). So, as Ubuntu wishes, **changing the layout** to `English (UK, international with dead keys)` solves the problem... and creates another: now I need to press `"` + `space` to get " ; at least now I can easily get á, ç, ã, ê, ü, etc...

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira Sorry I have a lot on my mind right now... I put your comment as an answer so other users can find it more easily. I think you can edit it if you want to improve it, it's a copy paste with one spell fix of behavior. Good luck on your paper btw.

Comment: @Alvar Tnx! I'd be mostly glad to get a link for a quick tuto on how to edit key combinations in Ubuntu... (tnx for the UK>US spelling fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solved! In the end both Alvar and the above mentioned question pointed
>   at the right direction. The solution is really meant to be "layout
>   changing" in Ubuntu...  even though I still strongly disagree with
>   such a label: the change is in behavior of certain key combinations
>   (input) to achieve desired characters (output), not in layout
>   (physical arrangement). So, as Ubuntu wishes, changing the layout to
>   English (UK, international with dead keys) solves the problem... and
>   creates another: now I need to press " + space to get " ; at least now
>   I can easily get á, ç, ã, ê, ü, etc.

*A direct quote from the comment on which Rodrigo de Oliveira posted his solution.*